# Does creating a new CNAME replace the old?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, cdn

I have a CNAME record:

```
cdn.example.com. IN CNAME examp.vo.llnwd.net
```

which was registered through Limelight.  Do I need to go back to Limelight release this record?  Or if I just generate a new CNAME for "cdn.example.com" through my domain registrar will it get replaced automatically?

My objective is to alias "cdn.example.com" directly to an EC2 server for the next few months while our traffic is light, and switch to a new CDN before our next surge.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It turns out that our domain registration at YahooDomains is pointing to MediaTemple namespace servers.  (I didn't set this up.)  That's why I was confused about the missing CNAME record.  So now I guess I need to track down the MediaTemple account and check the CNAME records there.  Does this mean that the CNAME records at YahooDomains are meaningless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace it in your primary dns server.  If that server is hosted by Limelight then that's where you need to change it.  If your domain was transferred to your new registrar and their server is now the primary for your domain then that's where you need to change it.

**EDIT**
To answer the question in your edit, yes.  If your NS records point to servers that are controlled by MediaTemple and not to YahooDomains servers then the CNAME record at YahooDomains is essentially useless.  You would need to add the CNAME to the server at MediaTemple.

Comment: See follow up question in edit

Comment: @mjhm Edited in response to your edit

Answer (score 1):

If you have full control (registrar side) over your domain, you can point the domain to an NS you have access to or can use the registrar provided DNS itself and add the necessary records to the corresponding NSs.

Comment: See follow up question in edit.